# Can't load search results Google Places ios Swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, swift4, google-places

I am using **GooglePlaces** for my app everything works perfectly but i don't know what happen suddenly i am getting error message "**Can't load search results**"           [image]

my API is already Enabled

[image]

**NOTE:** i had tried following solution but which is not works for me

[Google Places AutoComplete on iOS - Can't Load Search Results - Try Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165012/google-places-autocomplete-on-ios-cant-load-search-results-try-again?rq=1)

[Google Places iOS - Can't load search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855212/google-places-ios-cant-load-search-result)

Someone Please Help!

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I had tried all that answer given in that question but its not works for me that's why i asked new question

Comment: @RajeshKumarR and also i am not getting Try Again Button please check my screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved as i regenerate my google API keys