# Can't load search results - Google Places

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm using Google maps in my application, the autocomplete result not working (Can't load search results try again)!

[image]

I followed Google Maps's (Places API) [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete), I already enabled Places API into Google Cloud Platform and every run I runned with my **iPhone Device** and in the console I get this message:

> Error:  The operation couldn’t be completed. The operation failed due to exceeding the quota usage limit. See the usage limits guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/usage) for information on usage limits and how to request a higher limit.

And this message:

> with identifier: 'com.google.GooglePlaces'
>   2019-09-28 06:47:44.079967+0300 DemoGM[564:36414] [framework] CoreUI: RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier: 'com.google.GooglePlaces'

[image]

**NOTE:** I had tried following solution but which is not works for me:

[Can't load search results Google Places ios Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627648/cant-load-search-results-google-places-ios-swift)

[Google Places iOS - Can't load search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855212/google-places-ios-cant-load-search-result)

[Google Places AutoComplete on iOS - Can't Load Search Results - Try Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165012/google-places-autocomplete-on-ios-cant-load-search-results-try-again?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used over the quota usage limit.
[image]

If you want to use more then let's follow this one to upgrade: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/usage-and-billing

Comment: But the website said 0-100,000 it's free!!

Comment: Have you enabled billing? 
As the document said: `To use the Places SDK for iOS, you must include an API key with all API requests, and you must enable billing on each of your projects.`